# Проверка существования элемента в List

Tags: c#, data-structures, .net

Есть List<string> lst

Как проверить существует ли допустим lst[1] ?

Comment: Что понимается под "существованием"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (lst != null && lst.Count > 1 && lst[1] != null)
{
   // код
}
```

Comment: Проверка `lst[1]` не обязательно нужна: непонятно, что есть "существует" у ТС.

Проверка `lst != null` вредна, т.к. она не отличает нормальной ситуации (список пуст) от невыполнения контракта (lst == null).

Я бы написал так:

    if (lst == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("appropriate description");
    bool hasAtIndex1 = lst.Count > 1;